# Flask app running __main__ twice

Tags: python, flask

I am writing a Flask server and am having trouble understanding how to start the app without running `__main__` twice.

In a terminal, if I type `python example.py` it prints `Starting the app.` twice.

The contents of `example.py` are:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return some_object.get_something()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Starting the app.")
    some_object = object()
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this, after changing it to `= object()`

Comment: @TankorSmash thanks, I've updated the question.